# Cycle table rows in HTML/jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, html-table, row

I want to always show the first two rows, which i have done using .show(). And also want to show and cycle the next 4 rows, 2 at a time. 
So the 4 rows should show in my table, top 2 are fixed and bottom 2 rows to be replaced by the next two rows, every 5 seconds for example.

My jQuery code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
        $('tbody tr:even').css('background-color', '#114c00');      
        ticker();

        });

        function ticker(){
        $("tbody tr:#fixed").show();
        $("tbody tr:.hidden").hide(1000);
        }
</script>
```

My HTML

```
<table id="gradient-style" summary="Currency">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th scope="col" class="flag"></th>
            <th scope="col" class="currency"></th>
            <th scope="col" class="title"></th>
            <th scope="col" class="buy">We Buy</th>
            <th scope="col" class="sell">We Sell</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
        <tr id="fixed"><!----FIXED ROWS--->
            <td class="flags"><img src="flags/USD.png" /></td>
            <td >USD</td>
            <td>US DOLLAR</td>
            <td class="value"><span>3.1</span></td>
            <td class="value"><span>3.1</span></td>

        </tr>
        <tr id="fixed"><!----FIXED ROWS---->
            <td class="flags"><img src="flags/EUR.png" /></td>
            <td>EUR</td>
            <td>EURO</td>
            <td class="value"><span>5.10</span></td>
            <td class="value"><span>3.1</span></td>
            </div>

        <tr class="hidden"> <!--THIS SHOWS FIRST---->
            <td class="flags"><img src="flags/CAD.png" /> </td>
            <td>CAD</td>
            <td>CANADIAN DOLLAR</td>
            <td class="value"><span>8.10</span></td>
            <td class="value"><span>3.1</span></td>
        </tr>

       <tr class="hidden"><!---THIS SHOWS FIRST--->
            <td class="flags"><img src="flags/CNY.png" /> </td>
            <td>CNY</td>
            <td>CHINA YUAN</td>
            <td class="value"><span>8.10</span></td>
            <td class="value"><span>3.1</span></td>
        </tr>


       <tr class="hidden"><!---THIS REPLACES THE ROWS ABOVE--->
            <td class="flags"><img src="flags/CNY.png" /> </td>
            <td>CNY</td>
            <td>CHINA YUAN</td>
            <td class="value"><span>8.10</span></td>
            <td class="value"><span>3.1</span></td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="hidden"><!---THIS REPLACES THE ROWS ABOVE--->
            <td class="flags"><img src="flags/CAD.png" /> </td>
            <td>CAD</td>
            <td>CANADIAN DOLLAR</td>
            <td class="value"><span>8.10</span></td>
            <td class="value"><span>3.1</span></td>
        </tr>

    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: I would use a seperate table for the top 2 rows that don't change

Comment: Just a note, don't use this selector: `tbody tr:#fixed`. If you have an ID just us it. Ie. put `#fixed`. This allows jQuery/Sizzle to use the native `getElementById()` function instead of having to find all `tr` tags within all `tbody` tags. Aka it's faster.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var max = 0;
var index = 0;

$(function() {
    $('tbody tr:visible:even').css('background-color', '#114c00');
    max = $("tbody tr.hidden").length;
    ticker();
});

function ticker() {
    // hide all visible tr's with hidden class
    $("tbody tr.hidden:visible").hide();

    var l = index; // low
    var h = index + 1; // high
    $("tbody tr.hidden:hidden").filter(":eq(" + l + "), :eq(" + h + ")").show();

    // manage index
    index += 2;
    if (index >= max) index = 0;    

    // reset timer
    setTimeout("ticker()", 1000);
}
```

---

working example: http://jsfiddle.net/5vasr/

Comment: Thanks, if I then had 3 rows (instead of 2) alternating, which values do I need to change?

Comment: Edit: Never mind, I did it. Added an extra var x = index + 2;

Answer (score 0):

You need to look at setInterval:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setInterval

Your current code will only fire once.  Set an interval to have it happen repeatedly.

Edit: something like this for the javascript, untested, untried, but should get you started.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {
    var myInterval = false;
    $(document).ready(function(){

       //execute this function every 10 seconds
       myInterval = setInterval(function(){

           //show the first 2 matched selectors
           $('tr.hidden:lt(2)').removeClass('hidden').show();   

           //stop the loop when we are out of elements with the class "hidden"
           if($('tr.hidden').length == 0){
              clearInterval(myInterval);   
           }
       }, 10000);

    });
});

</script>
```

Comment: Unless you really want an interval, ie something that happens repeatedly.  (I prefer interval for just this kind of thing actually.)  So it's my personal preference, however I'm open, is there some reason it's not preferable?